# backbone.js sync using websocket

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, websocket

I'm trying to use WebSocket for replacing Backbone.sync method.

Then I created three instance of "Sample" model named sample1, sample2 and sample3 and call fetch() method. Each request was successfully sent to the server.

However, when response data coming from the server, every response is set to the sample1. In other word, backbone.js triggered change event and only sample1 instance catch it.

I know there's good library named backbone.WS. However i would like to know why below code didn't work properly. Please give me any comments.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ws;
   var url = ws://localhost:8080/application/sample;

   Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
      var data = JSON.stringify({
         'method' : method,
         'data' : model.attributes}
      );

      if(ws == null) {
         console.log("Create a new connection to the server.");
         ws = new WebSocket(url);
         console.log("Binding callback methods.");
         ws.onopen = onOpen;
         ws.onmessage = onMessage;
         ws.onclose = onClose;
         ws.onerror = onError;
      }

      function send(message) {
         // Wait until the state of the socket is not ready and send the message when it is...
         waitForSocketConnection(ws, function(){
            console.log("message sent!!!");
            ws.send(message);
         });
      }

      // Make the function wait until the connection is made...
      function waitForSocketConnection(socket, callback){
         setTimeout(
            function () {
                if (socket.readyState === 1) {
                    console.log("Connection is made")
                    if(callback != null){
                        callback();
                    }
                    return;

                } else {
                    console.log("Waiting for connecting...")
                    waitForSocketConnection(socket, callback);
                }

         }, 10); // wait 5 milisecond for the connection...
      }

      function onOpen(event) {
         console.info("Connection established to " + url);
      };

      function onMessage(event) {
         console.info("Message Received!");
         var message = JSON.parse(event.data);

         console.log("model: " + JSON.stringify(model.attributes));
         model.set(message);
      };    

      function onClose(event) {
         console.log(event.code);
      };

      function onError() {
         console.warn("There was an error with your websocket.");
      }

      send(data);
      console.log("Request is sent to the server.");
      options.success(message);
   };

   var Sample = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults : {
         id : 0,
         name : "default"
      }
   });

   var sample1 = new Sample({id:1});
   var sample2 = new Sample({id:2});
   var sample3 = new Sample({id:3});

   sample1.fetch();
   sample2.fetch();
   sample3.fetch();

   sample1.on("change", function(model) {
      console.log("--- onChange method in sample 1");
   });
   sample2.on("change", function(model) {
      console.log("+++ onChange method in sample 2");
   });
   sample3.on("change", function(model) {
      console.log("=== onChange method in sample 3");
   });
```

}